Restore SQL Server database - getting error Msg 3287
I am restoring a .bak file to a local database for the data received from a vendor. The .bak file is around 75+ GB in size.
I do NOT know the server version using which backup is created. I do NOT know original database name as well.
My SQL Server Version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64) Oct  8 2022 05:58:25
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: )

Command executed:
RESTORE DATABASE TSMAIN
FROM DISK = 'D:\MsSQL\Backup\TEST130510.BAK'
WITH RECOVERY
GO

I get this error:

Msg 3287, Level 16, State 1, Server DESKTOP-KEEKNNR\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
The file ID 1 on device 'D:\MsSQL\Backup\TEST130510.BAK' is incorrectly formed and can not be read.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server DESKTOP-KEEKNNR\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

What could be the issue?

You could ask the vendor for specifics?

run RESTORE FILELISTONLY, RESTORE HEADERONLY and RESTORE VERIFYONLY against your backup to get details what is inside. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-verifyonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

If the backup file is 75+ GB, then you have no chance restoring it to Express edition, which you seem to be using. SQL Server Express has a size limit of 10GB for a database. This is aside of any other problems you have with the backup file
